# Kodak Scanner Software Issue 0xc0000005

Tags: scanner

I am trying to be able to use a program called Kodak Smart Touch, but just today I have experienced an error preventing it from opening.

The scanner is a business class scanner, an i2900. It comes with a small program called Kodak Smart Touch. This program allows you to select and customize a number of presets on the front panel and automatically create/save scanned files, etc.

I was running a backup with Aomei Backupper at the time, and I wanted to scan a file. I tried to scan as normal, but right at the end the program quit with an error.

Now, whenever I try to start Smart Touch, even not running the backup and with Aomei uninstalled, the following error pops up:
Title of message: KSSCFG (version 1.7.15.121102) has stopped working. 
Body: See (path name) for more information.

When I go to the path in the error message, there are two files, ERRORLOG.txt and KSSCFG.dmp.
The error log says, "KSSCFG (version 1.7.15.322.121102) case an Access Violation(0xc0000005).
Error occur at 2014/06/11 21:37:54
Operation System: Windows 7 64bits (6.1.7601)
processor(s) type AMD x86 or x64"

The dump file can be downloaded here: 
http://l.bitcasa.com/yzbtv1VV

Opening it with a hex editor yields very little of use, but I do have an internal commandline utility that may help:
http://l.bitcasa.com/cTXvAsst

I've already uninstalled and reinstalled all the kodak software several times to no avail.

What is really odd is that the TWAIN and ISIS drivers work fine through another scanning program.

I am at my wit's end, and I have no idea what to do next. Thanks.

Comment: As someone that is certified to fix your scanner if you had actual *mechanical* issues, I really wish I could help you with this as well. :(

Comment: Oh right... Could you copy and paste the text from the dump file into something like pastebin? People aren't super keen on downloading random .exes from the interwebs.

Comment: No problem... I will post the hex on pastebin right here: http://pastebin.com/UgRdPH3Q

Comment: I also ran a sysinternals Process Monitor Scan to capture the startup process of both the bad program and a good start on a different machine. Let me know how to interpret that; they appear to be pretty much the same. I can also post them as well,

Comment: Ps. here is the hex from the dump converted to text: http://pastebin.com/Twf8q653

Comment: Really, as it is just a mini software program, was wondering if there could be anything that is inhibiting a complete removal. Perhaps a total and complete removal would be most effective. If so, does anyone have any tips?

Comment: For all those having the same issue, got it resolved. 
The install program drops a few files that prevent a clean reinstall.
They are located in:
C windows twain32 kodak
c windows system32 kodak
c program data kds_kodak
c user appdata local temp kds
and 
c program files kodak

Deleting all these folders entirely will solve the issue!